# TypeORM - Can I create a insert into query, with a subquery in the values?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

My Postgres DB has 2 tables: people and users.
people table has columns: "ID", "Name" and "Age".
users has: "ID" and "people_id"(foreign key).
I am trying to insert into users, all people who's age is 15, how can I do that without loading all the rows into the service?(in 1 insert into query perhaps?)
Example code I tried but isn't working:

```
const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('users')
      .insert()
      .into('users')
      .values((qb) =>
        qb
          .select('id', 'people_id')
          .from('people', 'people')
          .where('age = "15" '),
      );
```

I checked the subquery alone and it does return values.
When running the code currently I get this error:

```
"Cannot perform insert query because values are not defined. Call \"qb.values(...)\" method to specify inserted values."
```

Is it possible to do something like this? what am i doing wrong? thanks.